# putty serial autologin

Tags: command-line, bash, putty

I want to login to putty automatically via serial port through shell or bash script. This is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
tty=/dev/$(dmesg | grep tty | tail -n 1 | sed -e 's/ /\n/g' -e 's/\t/\n/g' | grep tty)
tty=${tty%:}
sudo chown "$USER":"$USER" "$tty"
putty -serial "$tty" -sercfg 115200
```

But if I change the last line of code to:

```
putty -serial "$tty" -sercfg 115200 -l $username -pw $password
```

I get the following output:

```
PuTTY: the -pw option can only be used with the SSH protocol
```

Is there an alternative command, always via Putty, always via serial port?

Answer (score 2):

**No**, you cannot pass a password when logging in over a serial line. Over a serial line, you are logged by a process that is called `[a]getty` and it will display a prompt for a username and a password.

Now, (because this PuTTY question appears off-topic to me) if you'd like to ask whether you could have a user 'logged in' at a serial port at all times without password, that answer is **yes**. Take a look at `man agetty` and search for `-autologin`.

Securty caveat: Needless to say that 'anyone' who is able to connect to your RS232 port with a dumb serial terminal (emulator), now gets in right away?